# more by developer inside the play store

Tags: android

I have 4 apps published. Lets name them A, B, C and D.
Whenever a user who has opened the page of app D, sees below the "More by the Developer A, B, C" is there a way to remove an app from the list ? Or, remove the "More by Developer completely"

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this is unpublishing the apps you don't want to show in the Google Play Console.